# Configuring Gstreamer with Eclipse CDT Juno for GStreamer plugin development

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, gstreamer, eclipse-cdt, gobject

I have Eclipse CDT installed in my Ubuntu 13.10. I'm new to GStreamer plugin development,and I came to know that Anjuta is being used by many developers. I don't know what features it does have, but I like to work on Eclipse, because of its autocomplete and handy shortcuts.

So, I want to know, First thing, What to download for GStreamer Plugin development in C, and

 how to configure GStreamer's plugin development libraries with Eclipse CDT, 
and the last one, how to launch and run the Gstreamer plugin, that I have developed.

Suggestions on how to start GStreamer Plugin development is most welcome :)

I'm currently reading GStreamer's plugin writers guide, so I would definitely appreciate a step by step instructions for the above process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm developing gstreamer plugins with eclipse under linux. You need to:

- install the gstreamer-devel packages

then if you want to get a plugin working really fast: download gst-template

```
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-template.git
```

and read the README files inside: you can get your first plugin by

```
cd gst-template/gst-plugin/src
../tools/make-element myplugin
```

then you compile this and you should have your first working gstreamer plugin. (concretely I copy the myplugin.c and myplugin.h generated to my eclipse environment where I compile them)
Includes:

1. /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 (or-0.10)
2. /usr/lib/glib-2.0/include
3. /usr/include/glib-2.0

and in the linker - Miscelaneous:

```
`pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0`
```